# How can I import pygame in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame, vscode-python

I've installed pygame on vscode but vscode can't import pygame showing this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with virtual environments make sure you are on the environment where pygame is installed when you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

1) open terminal in visual code
2) run command

> > pip install pygame

3)import pygame in your code